# Regex which returns false when string contains 2 non consecutive forward slashes (negative lookahead)

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to build a regex which should match when only one forward slash is found and false when 2 or more forward slashes are found. The capturing group is not used, olny if it matches, and the regex is executed by javascript.

```
/this-should-match
/this-should/not-match
```

I've tried a couple of regexps, including using a negative lookahead, but I can't seem to find the solution. Some patterns I've tried:

```
/\/(.*)(?!\/)/i
/\/(.*)[?!\/]/i
/\/(.*[?!\/])/i
```

Any regex genius over here knows the solution? I'm aware regex is meant to find an occurrence of a pattern, but there should be some solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negated character class instead of look arounds.

```
^\/[^/]+$
```

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string.
- `[^/]` negated character class. Matches anything other than `/`
- `$` Anchors the regex at the end of the string. Ensures that nothing follows the string that is matched by the pattern.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zT4gF3/2)

**Example**

```
"/this-should-match".match(/^\/[^/]+$/)
=> ["/this-should-match"]

"/this-should-match/not-match".match(/^\/[^/]+$/)
=> null
```